Counting lattice points trapped between surfaces
I'm trying to estimate the number of $\mathbb{N}^d$ points trapped between the hypersurfaces $\{ (x_1,...,x_d): x_1=1 \},....,\{ (x_1,...,x_d): x_d=1  \}$ and $\{ (x_1,...,x_d):x_1\cdot...,\cdot x_d =N \}$ for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$. I'll denote this number by $C(N)$.
More specifically, I hope to understand how $C(N)$ behaves asymptotically and to see how $\frac{C(N+1)- C(N)}{C(N+1)}$ behaves as $N\to \infty$.
I can estimate by computing the volume of the entrapped domain, but this is obviously a rough upper bound. Does any one on relevant methods to get these estimates?

@coiso You're right, I somehow missed this obvious fact. Thanks for pointing it out, though. I'll edit it.

FWIW: Writing $C(N)=\sum_{n=1}^NA(n)$ where $A(n)=#{\vec{x}\in\Bbb N_+^d\mid x_1\cdots x_d=N}$, we have $$A(n)=\prod_{p\mid n},\Bigl(!\Bigl(\begin{matrix}d\v_p(n)\end{matrix}\Bigr)!\Bigr)$$ where $\bigl(!\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} d \ v\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)!\bigr)=\binom{v+d-1}{d-1}$ is $d$ multichoose $v$. You can show this by applying stars-and-bars to the coordinates' prime factorizations... or Dirichlet convolutions to get $\sum A(n)n^{-s}=\zeta(s)^d$ and use multiset generating function on each Euler factor.

@coiso Can you clarify what you mean by $v_p(n)$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation
